# File Explorer add-on to do a quick image preview and show image dimensions?

Tags: windows-explorer, shell-extensions

When I am in file explorer and hovering over a filename which is an image, I would like to see a preview of the image and display its width and height dimensions. It needs to be quick.

Any such tools like a shell extension?

Answer (score 3):

[QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/) is a toolbar of Explorer, it provides "Tab Browsing" feature to Explorer. But one of its features is what you want. **When you hover over common image formats it shows a preview of the image like a tooltip.**

Comment: QtTabBar rocks! Can't live without it. Unobtrusively augments Windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

[XNView Shell extension](http://www.xnview.com/en/downloadwin32.html) does something similar with only registering a dll. It shows the preview of the image when you right click the image file in the context menu.